# iOS debugging with instruments - lag in real device

Tags: ios, lag, xcode-instruments

I am using Instruments (for the first time) as I am trying to debug a lag time arising on a real device but not on the simulator. I have collected some data but I am stuck now since I don't know very well how to interpret them.

Briefly, when I try to present a presentationController in my app I am faced with a lag time (about 5 sec) before the UIView appears on screen. I want to display a UITextView with attributed text. I registered the process with Instruments and here is what I can see (4 figures):

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

All I have understood so far is that there is maybe a problem with Core Graphics and Font. Could anyone help me to figure out what is going wrong and how I could get rid of this problem? I can give more code if needed.

**EDIT:**

This is what I obtained when applying the advice given, but I can still not figure out how I can refer those lines to my code.

[image]

Comment: With time profiler you want to on the right at the bottom with the check boxes tick them all, this will show which of your code is taking time

Comment: I am sorry but I have not undertood what you mean... Which check boxes are you talking about?

Answer (score 1):

You want to click these check boxes at the bottom of the time profiler:

from: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsk2T.jpg

to: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lK9rO.jpg

Now you should see your calls rather than all calls

Comment: I don't have this option in Instruments. The only things are menu items called "Compare call trees" and "Call tree data mining" but they cannot be selected (they are in gray)

Comment: Please refer to this documentation if you do not have the latest xcode:

http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ios/9629/profile-with-instruments/29732/time-profiler#t=201704061603167213308

Comment: Thank you. I did what you propose but how can I see which part of my code is problematic since I am running Instruments from my real device and since Xcode is not running?

Comment: Double click the line call you suspect is not performing correctly and it will show in you instruments, then you can click open in xcode

Comment: I think I must be missing something very elementary. When I start recording in Instruments, it starts my app on the device. Xcode is not running the app and when i double-click nothing appears and the xcode icon is shaded. How can I start recording the app from xcode and not the device?

Comment: no that is fine, just double click the call that you think is taking too long, do you see your own code in instruments when you double click a row?